# What do I need to build Tensorflow (from source) for c++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I want to build Tensorflow (GPU) from source for c++ but I always get errors when I try the build the pip package step. What do I need to make this step work?

I'm on Windows 10 but I have Cygwin if I need it. I am building Tensorflow for use with my GPU because I have a decent one so why not. The only advice I can seem to find is to switch versions of Bazel but I've already tried many different versions from 0.18.0 to the latest but I'm using 0.24.1 now because that seems to be the recommended version for Tensorflow 1.14. I am using CUDA 10.1 however but I don't see how that would cause this problem.

This is the command that I cannot get to work:

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I'm not sure what information is most necessary so here is the entire output. I've had different variations of errors but this is what it gives me now:

```
WARNING: The following configs were expanded more than once: [cuda, using_cuda]. For repeatable flags, repeats are counted twice and may lead to unexpected behavior.
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=70
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  'build' options: --python_path=C:/Users/Invilis Bella/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from b:\tensorflow\tensorflow\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --apple_platform_type=macos --define framework_shared_object=true --define open_source_build=true --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --spawn_strategy=standalone --strategy=Genrule=standalone -c opt --announce_rc --define=grpc_no_ares=true --define=PREFIX=/usr --define=LIBDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib --define=INCLUDEDIR=$(PREFIX)/include
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from b:\tensorflow\tensorflow\.tf_configure.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/Invilis Bella/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/Invilis Bella/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/lib/site-packages --python_path=C:/Users/Invilis Bella/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe --action_env CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1 --action_env TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=6.1 --config=cuda --config monolithic --copt=-w --host_copt=-w --copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --host_copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --copt=-DNOGDI --host_copt=-DNOGDI --verbose_failures --distinct_host_configuration=false --define=override_eigen_strong_inline=true --action_env TF_CONFIGURE_IOS=0
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:cuda in file b:\tensorflow\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --config=using_cuda --define=using_cuda_nvcc=true
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:using_cuda in file b:\tensorflow\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define=using_cuda=true --action_env TF_NEED_CUDA=1 --crosstool_top=@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:monolithic in file b:\tensorflow\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define framework_shared_object=false
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:opt in file b:\tensorflow\tensorflow\.tf_configure.bazelrc: --copt=/arch:AVX2 --define with_default_optimizations=true
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:cuda in file b:\tensorflow\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --config=using_cuda --define=using_cuda_nvcc=true
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:using_cuda in file b:\tensorflow\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define=using_cuda=true --action_env TF_NEED_CUDA=1 --crosstool_top=@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'repositories/repositories.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_docker//repositories': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 164
                _clone_or_update(ctx)
        File "C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 74, in _clone_or_update
                fail(("error cloning %s:\n%s" % (ctx....)))
error cloning io_bazel_rules_docker:
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: cd: too many arguments
+ cd C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external
/usr/bin/bash: line 3: cd: too many arguments
+ git -C 'C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/io_bazel_rules_docker' reset --hard 251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
+ git -C 'C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/io_bazel_rules_docker' fetch origin 251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa:251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
+ git -C 'C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/io_bazel_rules_docker' fetch origin 251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa:251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'repositories/repositories.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_docker//repositories': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 164
                _clone_or_update(ctx)
        File "C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 74, in _clone_or_update
                fail(("error cloning %s:\n%s" % (ctx....)))
error cloning io_bazel_rules_docker:
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: cd: too many arguments
+ cd C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external
/usr/bin/bash: line 3: cd: too many arguments
+ git -C 'C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/io_bazel_rules_docker' reset --hard 251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
+ git -C 'C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/io_bazel_rules_docker' fetch origin 251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa:251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
+ git -C 'C:/users/invilis bella/_bazel_invilis bella/ldshq52a/external/io_bazel_rules_docker' fetch origin 251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa:251f6a68b439744094faff800cd029798edf9faa
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.511s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Comment: might I suggest you use docker instead and all the dependency hell and installation worries go away: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Comment: @bolov ok I seem to have acquired tensorflow with the command `docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu` now it is unclear how exactly I am to use this in c++ or are there more steps? Where exactly did docker put these files anyway? Sorry for all the questions I am new to this whole thing I've never actually made an AI at least a legit one if you catch my meaning. I am interested in creating a deep neural net, for Q-learning I think will do for my purposes.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/ , https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers , https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp